# How do I read multiple excel files in SAS using a macro?

Tags: macros, sas

I would like to create one dataset within SAS by importing multiple excel files. The excel files have the same variables within and are saved in the same directory, the files all have consistent names:

excel_20150101
excel_20150201

How would I write this in SAS?

Answer (score 1):

This macro will loop through all Excel files in a Directory and will import the contents in datasets named : DS1, DS2, DS3 …. DS400(If there are 400 Excel files). Pease make sure to keep only Excel(.xlsx) files in the specific directory.

```
options merror mlogic mprint symbolgen spool;
%macro drive(dir,ext);                                                                                                                  
  %local filrf rc did memcnt name i;                                                                                                    

  /* Assigns a fileref to the directory and opens the directory */                                                           
  %let rc=%sysfunc(filename(filrf,&dir));                                                                                               
  %let did=%sysfunc(dopen(&filrf));                                                                                                     

   /* Loops through entire directory */                                                                                                 
   %do i = 1 %to %sysfunc(dnum(&did));                                                                                                  

     /* Retrieve name and import each Excel file */                                                                                                   
     %let name=%qsysfunc(dread(&did,&i));    
     proc import 
        out=DS&i
        datafile= "Y:\Excel\&name"
        dbms=XLSX replace;
        getnames=yes;
     run;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
   %end;                                                                                                                                

  /* Closes the directory and clear the fileref */                                                                                      
  %let rc=%sysfunc(dclose(&did));                                                                                                       
  %let rc=%sysfunc(filename(filrf));                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
%mend drive;                                                                                                                            

/* First parameter is the directory of where your files are stored. */                                                                  
/* Second parameter is the extension you are looking for.           */                                                                  
%drive(Y:\Excel,xlsx);
```

Comment: They are in multiple different excel workbooks rather than sheets, I want to loop through each file and then subsequently create one dataset. The sheets all start with the same text, just the dates that differ at the end.

Comment: Then you can pass the Excel name as parameter and omit the sheet = statement

Comment: Thanks, if using the two file names above, how would this be written? SAS newbie here.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to write this to loop through the files rather than writing out the last part of the macro? There are over 400 files.

Comment: Using the date part to write a do loop?

Comment: are the Excel names in a particular order? Say excel_20150101.. 0201.. 0301?

Comment: They are daily files, for example there will be 31 in January, 28 in February etc. YYYYMMDD

Comment: Yes you can dynamically list a folder into a table and then use that table to loop I will post an answer

Comment: Instead of creating 400+ data sets each time, are we able to then after the initial import to update it each time with the new daily file?

Comment: the names of Dataset are standard, when you want to combine all these datasets, you can simply write: Data all_files; set DS:; run; .. This code will be automatic.

Answer (score 0):

here is how you could create a dataset with all the file name and their path

```
%let windowpath=/data/exports/Analytics/Users/psamson/Travel_project/PCA/;

data file;  /*THIS PREPARE A TABLE OF TARGET FILE TO IMPORT*/
    length file $200 name $28;
    rc=filename("myfile","&windowpath");
    DirId=dopen("myfile");
    memcount=dnum(DirId);
    do i = 1 to memcount;
      fdir = "&windowpath./" ||  strip(dread(DirId,i));
      rc2=filename("fdir",fdir);
      fDirId=fopen("fdir");
      if fDirId > 0 then do;
        file = strip(dread(DirId,i));
        name = substr(strip(dread(DirId,i)),1,25);
        if index(file,'.xlsx') then output;  /*THIS ENSURE WE ONLY IMPORT CSV file */
      end;
      rc2 = fclose(fDirId);
      rc2= filename("fdir", "");
    end;
    rc = dclose(DirId);
    rc = filename("myfile");
    keep file name ;    /*KEEP THE 2 VARIABLE TO VALIDATE AND USE FOR IMPORT*/
run;
```

From this list loop trough the file table to call your import like in the macro above!

Comment: Note you may need to switch / to \ in the paths depending on your OS , the above was written for UNIX

Comment: Thanks both, really need this in SAS but good to know for unix also. Instead of creating 400+ data sets each time, are we able to then after the initial import to update it each time with the new daily file?

Comment: Oh SAS runs on windows and unix or linux. the path / to the files need to be based on your OS ! so is your SAS on windows or on Unix! it will help you understand SAS behavior sometimes

Answer (score 0):

So this is going to be interesting. When you import data from Excel the types are not controlled and you have little control. So I'm 99% certain you'll run into an issue combining data because the types will not align. I would recommend converting all your files to CSV (via batch script) and then importing all the CSV's at once.

Here's a macro I wrote that imports all:

```
%*Creates a list of all files in the DIR directory with the specified extension (EXT);
%macro list_files(dir,ext);
    %local filrf rc did memcnt name i;
    %let rc=%sysfunc(filename(filrf,&dir));
    %let did=%sysfunc(dopen(&filrf));

    %if &did eq 0 %then
        %do;
            %put Directory &dir cannot be open or does not exist;

            %return;
        %end;

    %do i = 1 %to %sysfunc(dnum(&did));
        %let name=%qsysfunc(dread(&did,&i));

        %if %qupcase(%qscan(&name,-1,.)) = %upcase(&ext) %then
            %do;
                %put &dir\&name;
                %let file_name =  %qscan(&name,1,.);
                %put &file_name;

                data _tmp;
                    length dir $512 name $100;
                    dir=symget("dir");
                    name=symget("name");
                    path = catx('\',dir,name);
                    the_name = substr(name,1,find(name,'.')-1);
                run;

                proc append base=list data=_tmp force;
                run;

                quit;

                proc sql;
                    drop table _tmp;
                quit;

            %end;
        %else %if %qscan(&name,2,.) = %then
            %do;
                %list_files(&dir\&name,&ext)
            %end;
    %end;

    %let rc=%sysfunc(dclose(&did));
    %let rc=%sysfunc(filename(filrf));
%mend list_files;

%*Macro to import a single file, using the path, filename and an output dataset name must be specified;
%macro import_file(path, file_name, dataset_name );

    proc import 
        datafile="&path.\&file_name."
        dbms=xlsx
        out=&dataset_name replace;
    run;

%mend;

*Create the list of files, in this case all XLSX files;
%list_files(c:\_localData\temp, xlsx);

%*Call macro once for each entry in the list table created from the %list_files() macro;
data _null_;
    set list;
    string = catt('%import_file(', dir, ', ',  name,', ', catt('test', put(_n_, z2.)), ');');
    call execute (string);
run;
```

Instead of this however, I recommend converting all files to CSV and then importing those. 
https://gist.github.com/statgeek/878e585102c14e01581f55dbe972d27e

And then importing all the CSV's at once into a single file:
https://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2018/10/09/read-multiple-text-files/